# Rails - Show form only

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a rails application that handles tool loan requests. I've scaffolded the model to handle all of the requests. I was wondering how I could make it so that when they access the request, to show only the form and not the index, and if possible, to have the index show on a different page.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!  Do you have any code demonstrating what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

In index action have something like this:

```
@object = Object.new
```

and in index.html.erb:

```
<%= render "form" %>
```